# active-jdbc: Include multiple database tables

Tags: java, apache-poi, activejdbc, activeweb

I am building one web application using activeweb. I am trying to export a table named `orders` which is related to other child table `dispatch` where the product detail for that orders is stored.

When I am trying to join the table using the below:

```
List<Order> orders1 = Orders.findAll().include(Dispatch.class);
```

After this am writing this data to a excel file using apache poi. Below is my code:

[image: Image for code screen shot]

I want to get the attributes from the `Dispatch` table.

But from `Order rowData=orders1.get(i)` I am not able to access the data in `Dispatch`. Only available items are those in `orders` table.

How can I get data from `Dispatch` model?

Comment: Please, turn on logging by providing a system property `-Dactivejdbc.log` and post the output here. Also, provide schemas for your Dispatch and Orders tables.

Comment: By the way, with 'post the output here' @ipolevoy means to edit it into the question, not answer your own question with the output. :)